# Test Controller Configuration Tool hanging/freezing on startup

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, microsoft-test-manager

I have Visual Studio Ultimate 2012, and I'm trying to create a Test Controller so I can test using Microsoft Test Manager... but when I start the Test Controller Manager, it's hanging/freezing at the start screen. I don't know what's going on. I've uninstalled/repaired it like 5 times already.

http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC612309.png

It's this screen, except I don't have the "Team Project Collection" portion. It's faded out/and I have a the "busy"/"loading" cursor...

Comment: I recommend to update the VS 2012, install an update for it.

Comment: I finally figured it out. For anyone having this same error, I deleted my QTControllerConfig.xml and then repaired Test Controller Configuration Tool in my Control Panel.

Comment: I tried mute's solution, but the Test Controller Configuration tool just hangs and spins.